# Detect all XMLHttpRequest calls are completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, xmlhttprequest

I have Javascript code that uploads files to a server. Each upload is done using a XMLHttpRequest object.

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

//...

xhr.open('POST', 'https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/', true);
xhr.send(fd);
```

The upload in parallel works fine. The problem is that **I need to detect when all of them have finished**, because I have to do a final submit, but only if all the uploads are completed.

My first try was save all the xhr objects in an array but I didn't know what to do with that :-(

```
var arrayxhr = [];

//...

//A loop {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    arrayxhr.push(xhr);

    xhr.open('POST', 'https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/', true);
    xhr.send(fd);
//}

//And now?
```

I found this jQuery function https://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/, but the same, I don't really know how to use it.

Can you help me please?

TIA,

Comment: Associate a callback for every xmlHttprequest, suppose number of request are 5, then make a variable say i = 5, and now in each callback, decrease it by one, and check if it is zero, if it is then run your final commit, as zero means all request are done, I hope it helps you, though it is late I Know. Tell me what do you think about this solution

Answer (score 4):

If you can use `jQuery` you can use `jQuery` AJAX [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) interface/methods and [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) method. `$.ajax/$.post/$.get` and other jQuery AJAX methods always return [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) object:

```
$.when($.get('someUrl'), $.get('anotherUrl')).then(function () {
    //all request complete
});
```

In native javascript you can use native [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or any promise library:

- http://www.javascriptoo.com/rsvp-js
- http://www.javascriptoo.com/Q (example https://gist.github.com/matthewp/3099268)

Also good article about Promises - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/.

Native `Promise` with `XMLHttpRequest` example:

```
function doAjaxRequest(method, url, data){
  var promise = new Promise();
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url, true);

  // Register the event handler
  xhr.onload = function(){
    if(xhr.status === 200){
      promise.resolve("Done");
    } else{
      promise.reject("Failed");
    }
  }; 

  data = data || {};

  xhr.send(data);

  return promise;
}

Promise.all(doAjaxRequest('post', 'someUrl'), doAjaxRequest('post', 'anotherUrl')).then(function (values) {
    //all request complete
});
```

Comment: It not cross-browser now, but you can use one of plenty libs and polyfills

Comment: Also add a native Promise example.

Comment: IE doesn't support Promises :-(  [http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises). I really need that the solution be cross-browser. Thank you for your help. I'm upvoting your answer, but I will need another solution...

Comment: Use `jQuery` or `Q` or `RSVP`. Just get examples from link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not exactly the answer to my question (detect that the asynchronous calls are completed), but this answer works for me. I copy here just in case it helps someone else:

> 2: On the client-side, create a stack of files to upload and upload
>   one at a time, calling the next one on the "Complete" callback of the
>   previous.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15557631/1893936